# SIP call getting status as "Default status message" in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, voip

I am working on VOIP call app for iOS. and I am using PJSIP library for that. If i make call using VOIP, some times i am getting `pj_status_t` status as value of 320010. and the message is "Default status message" and call is not connecting.
Why i am getting this error and how to fix this?
I have written the following.
        `pj_status_t status`;

```
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
            const pj_str_t *str = pjsip_get_status_text(status);
            NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc]
                             initWithBytes:str->ptr
                             length:str->slen
                             encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
            [self displayError:msg withTitle:@"Call error"];
}
```

Any help.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: No, I did not get.

Comment: so my issue is, I am not able to make a conference call when the app is in the background and it only happens ios 13 & later.

Comment: Sorry, No idea brother, Actually, I left that project 3 years back.